# Visual Studio Code: ignore language specific setting on sync

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to exclude a language specific setting in Visual Code from syncing. I already have excluded a non-specific setting, which works correctly:

```
"editor.rulers": [
    80
],
"settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [
    "editor.rulers",
]
```

However, I also have set this setting for a specific language:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.rulers": [
        88
    ]
}
```

This setting still gets synced. How can I exclude this as well?

Comment: I opened an issue for this:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/141140